# AC-DC Switching Power adapter Unstable Voltage

Tags: power-supply, ac-dc

I recently bought a AC-DC (14V DC, 3A) Power Supply on eBay to power a Samsung Monitor, and it does power on my monitor. It is not the monitor because another power adapter I have works with it.

Using a multimeter, the output voltage is unstable going from ~14V to ~13V repeatedly. Is the output filtering capacitors bad, or is it a switching mosfet that is bad?

Comment: Don't buy from non reputable dealers electrical goods/components that don't have a data sheet or a recognized manufacturer is my general advice.... <sub> how many times have I said this I wonder</sub>.

Answer (score 1):

Switch your multimeter to frequency measurement and see if it can pick up any ac components on the output. Better yet if you have access to an oscilloscope. Bad cap usually just won't work at all, undersized cap can cause unstable operation, or the low-pass part of power supply isn't designed properly are the options. I would discontinue use of that power supply.

Comment: Too bad I do not have a frequency measurement on my multimeter or an oscilloscope. :(